CnosDB query and insert very slow
environment: laptop, windows10, docker desktop cnosdb:community-latest
table with 4000 columns
SQL: select count(time) from booltest
CnosDB Query took 2.893 seconds.
insert: as slow as query
When use influxdb, the same table, insert 10 datum only takes 100ms around
CnosDB 2983ms vs  influxDB 100ms
